# How to decide whether to implement scrapy in a script or to use it as framework

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm creating a webpage which do two easy operations (mean and percentage calculation) according to around 20 figures taken from another three webpages (60 in total). I use Scrapy with the purpose of getting these 20 numbers, it´s going to be ran multiple times and, if it goes fine, at the same time with different variables.

The question is, should I implement the Scrapy functionality in a single script (CrawlerProcess), calling it from another where the variables are initialized rather than using the entire framework to get this little amount of data?

Comment: In both cases you are still using the whole framework. Calling it as a subprocess, instead of making it part of your code, may avoid `ReactorNotRestartable` issues, though.

Comment: For cases like this, I would use ScrapyRT ([docs][1]). Instead of calling a script, you do an API-request to the ScrapyRT server which scrapes the data and returns it in a json.